# Passing a query as a query parameter in JPQL Native Query

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to pass a query as a string parameter in another JPQL native query.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT (:query)", nativeQuery = true)
BigDecimal getTotal(@Param("query") String query);
```

So the resulting query would be something like the query below that returns me a value

```
SELECT (50 * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SOMETABLE))
```

but what I'm getting in return is only the string of `:query` parameter and not the result of the executed complete query.

Comment: What you are trying is not possible.
Parameters will be bound using a prepared statement and the you cannot pass a query.
Why don't you write a query with the real statement you want to execute?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i know it's a strange implementation but the query I'm passing as a parameter is generated and stored in a table and it represents part of a larger formula that can change so that's why I'm trying to build the query this way so I can create a single query with all the generated subqueries inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an interface for a custom repository `SomeRepositoryCustom`

```java
public interface SomeRepositoryCustom {

    BigDecimal getTotal(String sql);

}
```

2. Create an implementation of `SomeRepositoryCustom`

```java
@Repository
class SomesRepositoryCustomImpl implements SomeRepositoryCustom {

    private JdbcTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    public SomesRepositoryCustomImpl(JdbcTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal getTotal(String sql) {
        return template.queryForObject(sql, BigDecimal.class);
    }

}
```

3. Extend your JpaRepository with `SomeRepositoryCustom`

```java
@Repository
public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository, SomeRepositoryCustom {

}
```

to run a query

```java
someRepository.getTotal("SELECT (50 * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SOMETABLE))");
```